# Bootstrap: One modal not showing but other one is

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using react and bootstrap and am trying to make a page that includes multiple different popups. Right now I have 2 buttons which are meant to trigger seperate modals. The first one works exactly as intended while the second one simply doesn't do anything at all, no errors or anything, but it's definitely calling `.modal('show')`. All the other posts on the subject I could find were related to overloading css classes, but I don't have any custom css whatsoever and as I said, one of my modals is already working fine.

My page has a top level div `<div id="modal-root" class="container-fluid">` along side my "react-root" div. My react modal class is this:

```
class Modal extends React.Component{
    static modalRoot = document.querySelector('#modal-root');
    render() {
        let content = (
            <div className="modal fade" id={this.props.id} tabIndex={-1} role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">{this.props.header}</h5>
                            <button className="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span>&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                        {this.props.footer && <div className="modal-footer">{this.props.footer}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            content,
            Modal.modalRoot
        );
    }
}
```

which again, works just fine for my first modal.

The first modal has the following tag/button/triggering function:

```
<Modal id="playerSearchModal" header="Search Results:"> ,

<form className={className} onSubmit={this.doSearch}>
    ...
    <Button btnType="primary" type="submit" data-target="#playerSearchModal"> ,

doSearch(e){
    Ajax...
    $('#playerSearchModal').modal('show');
```

The second, non-functional modal has the following:

```
<Modal id={this.modalId} header={this.state.popup.header}>,

<Button key="schedule" btnType="outline-primary" onClick={this.doSchedule} value={entry.entrantId} data-target={this.modalId} data-toggle="modal" type="button">

doSchedule(e){
    ...
    $(this.modalId).modal('show');
```

I'm not sure if maybe you can only have one modal or something or if I'm just missing some silly mistake. Can anyone else see what might be going on?

Also, just in case it's helpful, the exact html being generated (according to chrome dev tools) is:

```
<body>
<div id="react-root">...</div>
<div id="modal-root" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="modal fade" id="playerSearchModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal fade" id="eventEntryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

You can see that there are some different attributes on the two child divs. Theses are all being generated automatically, not by me, and I reckon this difference is related to the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact a dumb simple mistake!

I have this line `$(this.modalId).modal('show');`

But `this.modalId` isn't a valid id on its own. It needs the `#`.

So it should be `$('#' + this.modalId).modal('show');`